# Pandas: How can you calculate rolling metrics (mean, standard deviation, z score, etc.) when using itertuples?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, time-series, rolling-computation

I am trying to calculate rolling metrics on financial time series data. I would like to use a looped approach to simulate testing on live data.

What is the most efficient way to calculate these rolling metrics in an itertuples loop?

Example Data:

```
DateTime                 Bid                                              
2006-01-03 00:01:07.588  0.85208       
2006-01-03 00:01:08.654  0.85213       
2006-01-03 00:01:08.859  0.85212       
2006-01-03 00:01:11.472  0.85215       
2006-01-03 00:01:12.002  0.85218  
...                          ...  
2020-03-15 23:59:57.150  0.85178  
2020-03-15 23:59:57.300  0.85179  
2020-03-15 23:59:58.233  0.85179  
2020-03-15 23:59:58.366  0.85178  
2020-03-15 23:59:58.595  0.85179
```

Code I have so far.

```
df = pd.read_hdf(r"F:\Market Data\2020.3.15 FXAUDCAD-TICK-NoSession.h5")
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DateTime']))
df = df.drop(columns=['DateTime'])

Rolling_Metric = []

for row in df.itertuples():
     ?
```

Comment: How will your live data come? The usual way to calculate windows is `df.shift()`, instead of generators or row-by-row calculation. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48084356/how-to-use-generators-in-pandas

Comment: @ChrisTang The data is from an API that returns either a window of data or the equivalent of a single row from the "Example Data" found above.

Comment: I'd like to confirm if the new data from API, either in window form or in a single row form, is after the time index you have collected right?

Comment: @ChrisTang Yes, the data would come in chronological order with each new data point falling some amount of time after the previous point.

Comment: Only to clarify:  You can't use [`DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think pandas is suitable for this problem.
If you have a data generating source like an api, here simulated by a generator

```
import numpy as np
def gen():
    while True:
        yield np.random.rand((np.random.randint(1,10)))
```

Which outputs data arrays of different sizes

```
for i in islice(gen(), 4):
    print(i)
```

Output

```
[0.1591485]
[0.40462191 0.32921298 0.64704824 0.9433797  0.44754502 0.47600713
 0.66130654]
[0.45582976 0.37764161 0.47205139 0.32354448 0.06795233 0.47943393
 0.13395702]
[0.0967848]
```

You can compute a rolling measurement for example with a window of 10 samples

```
import time
from itertools import islice

data = np.array([])
for new_data in islice(gen(), 5):              # get data
    for elem in new_data:                      # iterate through new data
        data = np.concatenate((data, [elem]))  # add new data row by row
        print(data[-10:].mean())               # get mean of last 10 observations
    time.sleep(.5)
```

Output

```
0.8251054981003462
0.5154331864262989
0.5677470477572374
0.6084844147856047
0.6532425615231122
0.6663683916931894
0.6768810511903373
0.6098697771903554
0.5976415974047367
0.5442112622703545
0.556721858529291
0.5851107975154073
0.6129548571751687
0.5519507890295304
0.47809901125252807
0.457599927037135
0.47739535574047764
0.5135494376774083
0.5620825459637069
0.5914086396034781
0.5554789093102113
0.6042456773490161
0.5860524867501515
0.6218627945520632
0.6509948271807725
0.6693775700674035
0.6657165569407465
0.6825455302579173
0.609296884720923
0.6708821735456445
```